# Elevation on AppBarLayout doesn't work

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-design-library, android-elevation

When I try to set a specific value to elevation for AppBarLayout, the shadow disappears completely.

```java
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:elevation="4dp">

     <!-- Toolbar -->
     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar...

     <!-- Other Layouts -->

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Is this a bug or the expected behaviour?

I'm using the version 26.0.0 of the design library.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Setting `Property Animation`

**Creating an animation with 1ms of execution time：`/animator/appbar_elevation.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="1"
        android:propertyName="elevation"
        android:valueTo="2dp"
        android:valueType="floatType" />
</item>
</selector>
```

**Setting it to AppBarLayout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:stateListAnimator="@animator/appbar_elevation">
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**And it can use in java code.**

```
appBarLayout.setStateListAnimator(AnimatorInflater.loadStateListAnimator(getContext(), R.animator.appbar_elevation));
```

Comment: This works, thanks! But it seems to me a hacky way to solve it. Why Is need to add an animator?

Comment: Because some way didn't work.I also used other ways.

Comment: @marc97 Could you tell me the hacky way to solve it?

Comment: I just feel like developing android apps becomes harder and harder each day because of these stupid bugs.

Comment: @mk_ ye. Demand more and more .And we must learn more and more .

Comment: @KeLiuyue thanks for your answer, I have referenced this to SO in Spanish: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/329139/android-studio-por-qu%c3%a9-la-propiedad-elevation-no-funciona/329163#329163

Comment: It's better to use ```android:duration="0"``` to make the change occur instantly

Answer (score 3):

Work for me:

```
    ViewCompat.setElevation(appBarLayout, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.toolbar_elevation));
```

Answer (score 3):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45703684/2551186) gives me cancer, why should one solve a missing elevation by adding an animation? Maybe this is bringing the desired result and some will say "if it works it works", but even a semi professional developer can spot the lack of code quality.

For anyone stumbling about this issue please use a more professional solution!

Usually you have a wrapper layout for your `AppBarLayout`, there you need to add `android:clipChildren="false"`. This will permit the shadow to be drawn outside the bounds of the `AppBarLayout`. In your included `Toolbar` you then simply set the desired elevation.

Minimal example:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:clipChildren="false">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:elevation="8dp" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, adding a `translationZ` helped:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/yellow_note"
    android:translationZ="4dp"
    android:elevation="4dp">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        ...>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            .../>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```