# style Toolbar for using with bottom app bar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, material-components, android-bottomappbar

How to style Toolbar in [this style](https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-bottom.html) as shown in Material Guidelines for Bottom App Bar?

It's white, has no elevation, has more title top padding than usual etc. I couldn't find any specs for it in Material Guidelines or any theme references in [material-components-android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/).

Screenshot:
[image: material design guidelines]

Comment: It's just a design, you can implement it however you deem appropriate.

Comment: @KeivanEsbati I know it's just a design. I was wondering if there are guidelines available for it.

Answer (score 0):

So, you're trying to achieve that white `Toolbar` with `BottomAppBar` together. It's so easy.

To do this, add `AppBarLayout` with `Toolbar` in `CoordinatorLayout`, place the the `BottomAppBar` and `FloatingActionButton` into parent `CoordinatorLayout` and set `app:layout_anchor` attribute of `FloatingActionButton` to reference id of `BottomAppBar` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/yourwhitebackground"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/yourwhitebackground"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:fabAttached="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="12dp">

    </android.support.design.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottom_appbar"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Read:** https://medium.com/@lupajz/the-place-for-bottomappbar-31e0db8f70b1 for more details.

Also, `app:elevation` might not work so, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45703684/4409113

Comment: My question is about the toolbar styling, not the FAB. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I have updated the answer. It was confusing at first but now, everything's clear.

Comment: I was looking for specs for it, not how to actually add a toolbar with a white background and no elevation.

Comment: My bad I thought you're looking for the buttombar implementation. that's just a design, just remove the elevation and make it white. Couldn't find any specs for that in material guidelines so, there might be none out there.

Comment: @Mohsen Elevation for bottom app bars has been fixed in release 1.1.0 (alpha)