# Android - Shadow on checkbox text - xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am struggling to add shadow on checkbox text, for some reasons it doesn't appear

```
 <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/travel__wizard_accept_chckbox"
    android:layout_width="234dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@dimen/travel__wizard_right_margin"
    android:layout_below="@+id/travel__wizard_licence_agree_view_button"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/travel__wizard_left_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:buttonTint="@color/white"
    android:shadowColor="@color/black"
    android:shadowDy="2"
    android:shadowRadius="4"
    android:text="@string/oetr__accept_licence_text"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

Comment: Try `android:elevation`, if you target android 5.0 above. (See answer of @user7832102)

Comment: You can try [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45703425/elevation-on-appbarlayout-doesnt-work/45703684#45703684](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45703425/elevation-on-appbarlayout-doesnt-work/45703684#45703684)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Your Solution is here :**

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/travel__wizard_accept_chckbox"
    android:layout_width="234dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@dimen/travel__wizard_right_margin"
    android:layout_below="@+id/travel__wizard_licence_agree_view_button"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/travel__wizard_left_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:buttonTint="@color/white"
    android:shadowColor="@color/black"
    android:shadowDy="2"
    android:shadowRadius="4"
    android:text="@string/oetr__accept_licence_text"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

Apply it.
You can use `android:elevation`  attribute for a shadow effect.

Answer (score 1):

I use style for this one.

Here is my CheckBox and style.

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/travel__wizard_accept_chckbox"
    style="@style/CheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="THIS TEXT"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<style name="CheckBox" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:shadowColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">2</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">2</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">4</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```